# Optimization Algorithm

Tags: java, optimization

Im currently writing a java program that reads in a CSV file and creates objects and sorts them into 5 different ArrayLists. This much i've completed, every object has a price and a value and I'm now trying to write a method that finds the best possible combination (judged by value) that can be afforded within the budget. I'm wondering the best algorithm for optimization, I can't seem to think of the best way to do this.

Comment: **best possible combination** this is your business logic

Comment: Best in what way ?

Comment: Looks like a Knapsack problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)